# Sequelize field association

Tags: database, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables. How to link field in first table with `id` field in second table in Sequelize? Example:

First table:

```
id | author | text
1  | 2      | 'test1'
2  | 2      | 'test2'
3  | 1      | 'test3'
```

Second table:

```
id | name 
1  | John
2  | Jane
```

On request values from first table result should contain name in `author` field. Example:

```
first.findAll().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Returns it:

```
id | author | text
1  | Jane   | 'test1'
2  | Jane   | 'test2'
3  | John   | 'test3'
```

(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/).

Your models will look something like this

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Table1 = sequelize.define('Table1', {
    text: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING
    },
    authorId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: "Table2",
      referencesKey: "id",
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Table1.belongsTo(models.Table2, { foreignKey: 'authorId' })
      }
    }
  });
  return Table1;
};

'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Table2 = sequelize.define('Table2', {
    name: {
      type:DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Table2.hasMany(models.Table1, { foreignKey: 'authorId' })
      }
    }
  });
  return Table2;
};
```

And it seems like you want to eager load your authors.

```
Table1.findAll({
    include:[
        { model: Table2 }
    ]
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result.get({plain:true})
})
```

Comment: But if table2 contains many fields, how to specify field `name`?

Comment: @Vladimir37 `Include` will left join the table. You will end up with a table1 result with a Table2 object that has the field `name`.

Comment: I do not understand. You can sample code that would have done the same thing, but if there are many fields in table 2?